# What is Swift µframework?

Tags: swift, frameworks

What is Swift µframework or µframework in general? Apparently Google gives only examples of those frameworks, but doesn't provide any clear explanation of what it is.

Comment: The explanation below by dpassage is pretty sufficient for me. No need for answers in a few paragraphs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: upvoted to nil. what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context, "µframework" is short for "microframework", which really just means a very small framework which adds a specific small piece of functionality.

The canonical example of this is [Result](https://github.com/antitypical/Result), which adds just a single type to the Swift system.

Contrast with frameworks like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) or [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift), which add a whole suite of functionality around a particular area.